# Which EU countries prohibit electoral riggers for holding leadership positions (political and/or within public administration)?

Tags: european-union, law, election-fraud

At the end of February 2018, Romanian General Prosecutor talked about the so called [Troesmis Constitution](http://iusromanum.eu/documents/985691/3147559/Romeo+Cirjan.pdf/f42cc993-31ba-4e50-bdc2-a3986471a446) ([source in Romanian](https://www.hotnews.ro/stiri-esential-22315184-augustin-lazar-redat-patrimoniului-national-constitutia-troesmis-care-prevedea-inca-din-anul-170-nu-deveni-demnitar-cel-care-prin-viclesug-fraudat-alegerile.htm?cfsyn), approximate translation below):

> He will not become a dignitary, a duke, a quaestor, an edil, or a
>   sacerdot who, through perfidy, has defrauded the election. Will pay
>   the budget of Marcum Aurelium Augustum Troesmensium 10,000 fine (..)'

The original text referenced by the Romanian official is the following:

> Whoever is appointed in a manner different than the one allowed by
>   this law, shall be neither annual duumvir, nor quinquennalis, nor
>   aedilis, nor quaestor. And, whoever appoints them deliberately, in bad
>   faith, shall be forced to pay 10 000 sestertii to the citizens of
>   municipium M. Aur. Ant. and L. Aurel. Commod.

This is clearly related to the [main party in power leader](https://www.economist.com/news/europe/21711729-despite-its-leaders-voting-fraud-conviction-democratic-party-wins-landslide-romania), who is also a head of one of the Parliament's Chambers.

I am wondering how many modern states keep this principle, by not allowing electoral riggers for accessing high official positions.

**Question:** Which EU countries prohibit electoral riggers for holding leadership positions (political and/or within public administration)?

Comment: @SJuan76 - no, I only mean restriction for public sector or politics positions. Fixed the question to reflect this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there must be little people who knows enough of the laws of all 27 EU countries, I am posting this as a community wiki. Feel free to add the data about the countries you know.

I am making two lists here: Countries that forbid riggers from holding office/working for the public administration. That way, it will be easier to tell if a country is not listed because there is no answer or because it does not use such punishment.

**Countries that may forbid holding public office or work for the public administration**

- Spain. The [electoral law (link in Spanish)](http://www.juntaelectoralcentral.es/cs/jec/loreg) begins its VIII Chapter (Electoral Felonies and Faults) with the Article 137:

  > Por todos los delitos a que se refiere este Capítulo se impondrá, además de la pena señalada en los artículos siguientes, la de inhabilitación especial para el derecho del sufragio pasivo.

  or

  > For all of the crimes related in this Chapter there will be, in addition of the punishment established in the following articles, that of special disqualification for the rights of passive suffrage.

  ("Passive suffrage" meaning the possibility of being elected.)

  Time is not specified, but since most of the sanctions become as [day-fines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day-fine) I think it safe to assume that it would be for the same duration that was specified as day-fines. Doubly so when the sanction involves jail.

  Disqualification for working in the public administration (in any position) appears explicitly in several articles (voting multiple times, buying votes). Apart from that, it seems that if a public worker is sentenced to more than three years of prison he would lose his place and could not apply for a new one after he were released.
- The United Kingdom [remove in December 2020]. Under [the Representation of the People Act 1983](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1983/2/section/160), an election court petitioned to investigate an election has certain duties, including producing a report of the investigation.

> - The report of the election court under section 144 or section 145 above shall state the names of all persons (if any) who have been proved at the trial to have been guilty of any corrupt or illegal practice ...
> - The report shall be laid before the Director of Public Prosecutions.
> - Subject to the provisions of subsection (4A) and section 174 below, a candidate or other person reported by an election court personally guilty of a corrupt or illegal practice —
>
>   1. shall during the relevant period specified in subsection (5) below be incapable of —
>        (i)being registered as an elector or voting at any parliamentary election in the United Kingdom or at any local government election in Great Britain,
>        (ii)being elected to the House of Commons, or
>        (iii)holding any elective office; and
>   2. if already elected to a seat in the House of Commons, or holding any such office, shall vacate the seat or office as from the date of the report.

---

**Countries that may not forbid holding public office or work for the public administration**